# Rated Mature Android App Releases in Foreign Countries

Tags: android, rating

I'm developing a crime themed android game that will have a high maturity rating (references to drugs, gangs, violence). I'm worried about distributing it on foreign android markets because of it's high maturity rating. Is there somewhere I can look for app restrictions for other countries app markets? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Market Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) to restrict where you app is sold. See the [Other Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html#other-filters) section for more details.

Comment: Yes, I used filters with my first app release. Well, I checked all countries because the rating was low. One month later, about 30% of the sales were from outside the US. So, I would like to release this game in as many countries as possible, but it would really suck if I get an email because I'm being fined/sued for the apps maturity rating.

Comment: If the country doesn't allow mature apps to be sold in it, then they just won't show up as available in the market.